# How to make turtle drawn shape move around using arrow keys

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have to import a turtle and make it draw a square. I have that step done but the next step is to make that square move around the screen using the arrow keys. I already added the code which should allow that to happen but the turtle is still not moving. It just appears on the screen and I'm pressing the arrow keys but nothing moves. I'm not sure what the error in my code is.

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(300,300)
screen.tracer(0)

def square():
  for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)

def move_up():
  turtle.setheading(90) #pass an argument to set the heading of our turtle arrow
  turtle.forward(15)

def move_right():
  turtle.setheading(0) #the direction is east
  turtle.forward(15)

def move_down():
  turtle.setheading(270) #the direction is south
  turtle.forward(15)

def move_left():
  turtle.setheading(180) #the direction is west
  turtle.forward(15)

while True :
    turtle.clear()
    square()            #call function
    screen.update()         # only now show the screen, as one of the frames




screen.onkey(move_up, "Up") 
screen.onkey(move_right, "Right")
screen.onkey(move_down, "Down")
screen.onkey(move_left, "Left")
screen.listen()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you tried to write the entire program at once: you didn't bother to test the pieces, and now you're in a situation where you have to fix several errors in order to get *any* useful output.  Back up, program one part at a time, and *test* each part before proceeding.

Your immediate problem is that you have not bound keys to actions when you need them:

```
while True :
    turtle.clear()
    square()            #call function
    screen.update()         # only now show the screen, as one of the frames

screen.onkey(move_up, "Up") 
screen.onkey(move_right, "Right")
screen.onkey(move_down, "Down")
screen.onkey(move_left, "Left")
screen.listen()
```

You have an infinite loop in front of your bindings: you never get to this code, so there's no attention to the arrow keys, and your screen isn't `listen`ing.  You have to do these things *before* your loop.

You also seem to be confused about which methods apply to an object, and which you call as class invocations.  You have not instantiated a Turtle object to take movement commands.

I recommend that you return to your class materials and work more slowly through each technique.  Add each to your program as you learn it ... and *test* before moving on.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I was able to resolve my problem. Thank you again.